# If I have a blog on Tumblr that is also embedded on my website - will this negatively impact my search engine rankings for either URL?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, embed, tumblr, ranking

If I have a blog on Tumblr that is also embedded on my website - will this negatively impact (because of duplicate content) my search engine rankings for either URL?

Comment: How do you embed it on your site?

Answer (score 2):

It is very likely that it will, unless the embedding is done through an iframe. You could try using canonical URLs (see [Google reference](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394), [SEOMoz tips](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/rel-confused-answers-to-your-rel-canonical-questions)) to point both URLs to whichever one you want to rank. To be safer, I would recommend showing snippets or a feed of some sort on your website that links back to your tumblr, or just moving everything over to your website via some other platform and forgetting the tumblr. (Yahoo recently bought Tumblr, and based on previous Yahoo acquisitions there is speculation that Tumblr's days may be numbered anyway.)

Comment: it's sort of a double edged sword in my mind. because on one hand the blog is in the tumblr network and can be reblogged or whatever- spread that way and on the other hand the same blog is on my site for those visitors. i'm not sure if the positives outweigh the negatives. can you show me a link that talks about specifics with the canonical urls? i also found this "Allow search engines to index your blog" i can check that off in tumblr, do you think that could help?

Comment: Info on use of canonical tags here:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394
They can be used across different domains, but I don't think you can set canonical tags on Tumblr, so you would have to set the canonical tags on your blog referencing Tumblr, which means for all intense and purposes Google will drop the blog on your site in the SERPS over the tumblr blog. Disallowing search engines to index the tumblr blog sounds the best idea. With the Tumblr blog no longer indexed, there will be no duplicate content worries & the blog on your site stays in the index.

Comment: Just ensure it is blocked once clicking it, like checking all posts are blocked and not just new ones; I'm not really sure how Tumblr handles blocking on their site.

Comment: Added moobot's link and an additional reference.